# xcode camera check in simulator

Tags: objective-c, camera, uialertview

I've got the camera running in my app, and in the simulator the button to access it is disabled, however I also have an alert that pops up if the user never uses it. I don't want that to appear if their device doesn't have a camera, and I've used :

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    //alert
}
```

but in the simulator it's still running the alert. Unfortunately I don't have a device without a camera to test it on, and I'm not sure if there is an issue or not. I wouldn't expect it to run as the simulator doesn't have a camera, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I'm using for this purpose:

```
- (void) initializeCamera {
    AVCaptureDevice* device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

    if(!input) {
        // running on simulator or something else without camera
        NSLog(@"camera is not found");
    }
    else {
        // camera exists, you can alert
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for that, if i get it to work ill accept and up vote. Do you have any ideas why what i have wouldnt be working?

Comment: So im not able to use AVCaptureDevice at all. Do i need to do something before i can access it? im running latest xCode by the way.

Comment: @Onkyo You need to link the `AVFoundation` framework to your project.

Comment: cheers, got it to work, even though my way ended up working anyway, for some reason... I commented it out to try your way, and then when i uncommented it was fine... Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 This check does not work in simulator with iPad, iOS 5.0. It works on a real device.